# How to resolve all .dev domains to localhost on Windows

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, dnsmasq

We'd like to set things up on our developers' Windows boxes such that all `.dev` domains resolve to localhost.  On Unix systems, firing up dnsmasq with a single additional line to `hosts` would do it, but dnsmasq is sadly Unix-only.  On the Windows side, I'm not aware of an equivalent solution, either built-in or available in a third-party utility.  The best I've been able to come up with are some PowerShell scripts, running as administrator, that would alter `c:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts` directly—ugly and error-prone at best.

What's the right way to do this?  Does no solution meaningfully exist right now?

Comment: I don't think the hosts files in Windows supports wildcards.  You could do what TheFiddlerWins is suggesting and set a wildcard A record to 127.0.0.1, but yes it would go to all Windows clients using that DNS server.  Probably doesn't matter since it is a .dev though.  But mixing "production" and "development" is typically taboo.  Why the need?  Can't the dev peeps create their own entries as they build up a local site/server/host?

Comment: The issue here is that there are a collection of sites (`foo.com`, `bar.com`, etc.) that talk to each other; we'd like to make it so that their location on the dev boxes is similar (`foo.dev`, `bar.dev`), which allows for consistency without editing the hosts file for each site.  Making new virtual hosts in IIS would be sufficient.

Comment: This seems like a duplicate of the following answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/138162/wildcards-in-a-windows-hosts-file?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: Everyone, beware - .dev domain is now TLD: https://domains.google/tld/dev/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have a .dev zone in DNS already? You can create a wildcard entry where *.dev goes to the loopback.

Comment: We don't; you're proposing doing this at the AD level, so that any machines on the domain would pick it up?

Comment: It's not really at the "AD" level, although if you use AD integrated DNS and create the zone as such it would work out that way - it would be for any machine that resolved against that DNS server(s).

Comment: Got it.  That sounds a lot saner than doing this on each box.

Answer (score 8):

Alternative: get your devs to just append [.localtest.me](http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/archive/2012/05/14/introducing-testing-domain-localtest-me.aspx), which is a public DNS zone that already exists (with a * A record) for this purpose.

Comment: I'm not sure that adding an untrusted public domain to your workflow is a great plan!

Comment: If this concerns you, it would be simple to add a DNS test to whatever monitoring solution you use. If the DNS for localtest.me has changed in the last second, make it blast an alert to your devs.

Answer (score 5):

I have resolved this situation using Acrylic DNS Proxy. It's a free, open-source software for Windows that allows you to wildcard a folder as local top domain registry.

1. **Download Acrylic DNS Proxy here:** http://mayakron.altervista.org/wikibase/show.php?id=AcrylicHome
2. **Configure your Network settings to point to your local IP address as explained here:** http://mayakron.altervista.org/wikibase/show.php?id=AcrylicWindows10Configuration
3. **Open your Acrylic config file here:** Start > Programs > Acrylic DNS Proxy > Edit Custom Hosts File (AcrylicHosts.txt)
4. **Add your wildcarded top level domain like this:** `127.0.0.1   *.dev`
5. **Restart Acrylic like this:** Start > Programs > Acrylic DNS Proxy > Restart Acrylic Service
6. **Add the wildcard to your Apache config file. It may look similar to this:**

It may look similar to this:

```
LoadModule vhost_alias_module modules/mod_vhost_alias.so  

NameVirtualHost *.dev:80  

<Directory "/www/sites">  
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI  
    AllowOverride All  
    Order allow,deny  
    Allow from all  
 </Directory>  

 <VirtualHost *.dev:80>  
     VirtualDocumentRoot c:/www/sites/%-1/%-2+/  
 </VirtualHost>
```

That should do the trick.

Answer (score 3):

I can recommend http://localhost.tv - all subdomains resolve to 127.0.0.1

Comment: I'm not sure that adding an untrusted public domain to your workflow is a great plan!